# Подскажите как отловить файл который был загружен в админке?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Мне нужно распарсить(налету) файл который был загружен через админку.Как его отловить?

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product, Task
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   pass

admin.site.register(Task,TaskAdmin)
```

models.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(verbose_name="id_products")
```

Comment: Ищите его в папке, в которую загружаете файл. Пути загрузки должны быть указаны в файле settings.py в переменной MEDIA_ROOT.

Comment: `post_save`, `pre_save`